# Google Earth coordinates and Aperture place

Tags: aperture, google-maps

I'd like to geo-tag some already-imported photos in Aperture.

To get the correct location, I'm using Google Earth. However, when I copy/paste the coordinates into Aperture Places, the maps shows a completely different location.

Here's an example. The coordinate is

```
4°15'13.02" N 118°38'00.54" E
```

I use [this converter](http://www.earthpoint.us/Convert.aspx) to get a LatLon coordinate

```
04.2536167°, 118.6334833°
```

but when I paste this value in Aperture, the Place doesn't match on the map. The location seems to be correct, because when I use this in Google Maps it shows the same point.

Any hint on geolocating a photo in Aperture?

Answer (score 2):

An applescript to take care of this:  http://www.underdoug.ca/2012/08/13/geotagging-with-google-earth-and-aperture/